# No matching distribution found for tensorflow(from versions: none)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have python3.8.17 and using MacBook Air(M1, 2020), trying to install tensorflow following the instruction on TensorFlow webpage using conda, the miniconda environment has been successfully installed, but when I use command:

```
pip3 install tensorflow
```

It keeps reminding:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow
```

I also tried to use URL of the TensorFlow Python package by command:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-2.13.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl 
ERROR: tensorflow-2.13.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_10_15_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

How could I fix this issue? Appreciate for any kind help!!